# Is possible to copy a data range from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, spreadsheet

```
function transferDataToDataBase(){
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
    var DB = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID");
    
    var SCPM_Input = ss.getSheetByName("Report")[0];
    
    var history_Input = DB.getSheetByName(Database);
    
    var blankRow = history_Input.getLastRow();
    
    SCPM_Input.getRange(("A2:T").copyTo(history_Input.getRange(blankRow+1,1,blankRow+1,20));
    
}
```

Question:

1. The last line has an error at ";", don't know how to fix it. It said the syntax error;
2. It seems copy To only works for transferring from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet, but not in between spread sheet. Is there a way to copyTo between spreadsheets?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the formatting as well then copy the entire sheet/tab and then use copyTo() to copy the range and then delete the copied sheet.  Or if you just want the data use getValues() and setValues();

This is part of the problem:

`var SCPM_Input = ss.getSheetByName("Report")[0];` because the index zero at the end should not be there and you cannot have sheet.getLastRow() + 1 number of rows in a sheet as shown in the next row.

`SCPM_Input.getRange(("A2:T").copyTo(history_Input.getRange(blankRow+1,1,blankRow+1,20));`

And copyTo doesn't work between spreadsheets.

Comment: Many thanks. I have deleted [0] and it doesn't give the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update:
Since the database will be used by multiple users. I set up a standalone database. I copied my "Report" sheet from spreadsheet 1 to spreadsheet 2. It will create a sheet "copy of Report".I rename, copied to Database sheet and delete it.

Feel free to discuss if there is an easier way to do it. Thanks.

// transfer the report to DataBase Spreadsheet

function transferDataToDataBase(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var db = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet ID')

var scpm_Input = ss.getSheetByName("Report");

scpm_Input.copyTo(db);

Utilities.sleep(3000);

db.getSheetByName('copy of report').setName('Import')

var history_Input = db.getSheetByName('Database');

var blankRow = history_Input.getLastRow();

var target = db.getSheetByName('Import');

target.getRange("A2:T").copyTo(history_Input.getRange(blankRow+1,1,blankRow+1,20));

history_Input.getRange(blankRow+1,21).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd h:mm") //update the date and time

db.deleteSheet(target);

}