# Copying Data from One Spreadsheet to Several Others with Array and For Loop - Repost as suggested did not solve

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following appears to work, however the code times out. A portion of the data is transferred to the 1st sheet of the loop and then the following error occurs: "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id "Y". CopyCmpstrs @ Code.gs:33" For the purpose of the post, I removed the actual spreadsheetIDs.

The following has been suggested as a solution, however this only deals with data within the same spreadsheet and is a separate issue. The issue that I am having, I think, is that the dataset is large and the 2nd sheet being pasted to is freezing: Is possible to copy a data range from one spreadsheet to another?

[Is possible to copy a data range from one spreadsheet to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779550/is-possible-to-copy-a-data-range-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another)

```
function CopyCmpstrs() {
  var DashboardSSID = "X";

  var PaymentSSID = "Y";
  var SalesSSID = "Z";
  var FormsSSID = "A";
  var ProductSSID = "B";
  var InvoiceSSID = "C";

  var TargetSSID = [PaymentSSID,SalesSSID,FormsSSID,ProductSSID,InvoiceSSID];

  var ssSource = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DashboardSSID);

  var CmpstrsSheet = ssSource.getSheetByName("Cmpstrs");
  var CmpstrsSheetName = CmpstrsSheet.getName();

  var RowCountSource = CmpstrsSheet.getRange(1, 2).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var CustomerData = CmpstrsSheet.getSheetValues(1,1,RowCountSource,176);

  var ArraySize = TargetSSID.length;

for (var i=0; i<= ArraySize; i++){
  var TargetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TargetSSID[i]);
  var TargetSheet = TargetSS.getSheetByName(CmpstrsSheetName);

  var MaxRow = TargetSheet.getMaxRows();
  var MaxCol = TargetSheet.getMaxColumns();

  var TargetFullRange = TargetSheet.getRange(1,1,MaxRow,MaxCol);
  TargetFullRange.clearContent();

  var TargetRange = TargetSheet.getRange(1,1,RowCountSource,176);
  TargetRange.setValues(CustomerData);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you just want the data you can use getValues() and setValues() if you want the formattingg then copy the sheet to another spreadsheet and then you copyTo to copy the  data and formatting and delete the recently copied sheet.

Comment: .copyTo only works within the same spreadsheet 

The issue appears to be with the data size. I will attempt to change .getSheetValues to .getValues.

It appears that .getValues is now .getSheetValues, so this suggestion does not solve the issue. 

I believe the issue has to do with the data size being transferred however I would expect this to be able to be handled by sheets/google.

Comment: I understand that  read the comment  completely.

Comment: It was and has again been read in full. I do not see how your suggestion can help solve the problem as .copyTo only works within one spreadsheet, not across two different files.

Comment: The first copy copies the tab from one spreadsheet to another and the second copies the content and formatting within the second spreadsheet and then you delete the copied sheet.

Comment: The suggested approach is what I currently have impleted.